# Should I use a VPN with Orbot?

Tags: vpn, orbot

Should I use Orbot with a proxy or VPN? If so should I place it before or after Orbot's connection to the Tor network?

Comment: People should make more accessible how to safely root devices. I feel it is difficult like installing Linux on a computer that does not have the compatibility with it (you know how it gets complicated installing linux last versions on old computers or especially on pc that do not allow a certain structure\compatibility with it... ) the same thing is with root, seems so difficult to do. Please share.

Answer (score 3):

Similar q/a linked below should also apply here.  Not necessary imo. Although it might be more secure to use orbot's built-in transparent proxying (requires a rooted device)  which will torrify additional system applications/etc that you or the browser connect with.

[Secure my connection with VPN router & Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/445/secure-my-connection-with-vpn-router-tor)

Answer (score 0):

Updating for 2018: Orbot now allows transparent torrification without root on android and ios devices. However this is not always beneficial as it forces identifying information through Tor which can de-anonymize you at the exit. I personally now use a multi-hop vpn and Orbot simultaneously to allow the use of Orfox through Tor and everything else through vpn. This is possible on android as of v 7.0.