# How to connect to a VPN, then to Tor?

Tags: vpn

I know it's possible, but how exactly I can do that? I am not able to find any specific tutorial. And will this protect me even if the website is not using HTTPS?
Thanks regards!

Comment: If a site isn't using HTTPS, the Tor exit node can view and modify everything going between you and the site.

Comment: I am aware of that, but my priority is anonymity - if the site isn't using HTTPS, I am easy to track. But if I connet with VPN to TOR, all they will be able to see will be the VPN.

Comment: Will this (connecting to VPN and then to TOR) protect me when I am not using HTTPS site? They will be only able to see that VPN, I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure my connection with VPN router & Tor](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/445/secure-my-connection-with-vpn-router-tor)

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions for your question above.

1. First of all there are different VPN companies that offer VPN which routes the traffic through TOR thus airvpn and bestvpn.
2. Another solution can be that you are going to use [whonix](https://www.whonix.org/).
3. A less secure solution is that you connect first on your VPN for example openvpn and then you can use [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en).

It should be very boring to explain here for example how whonix/openvpn/tor browser is working. I let you read and learn and find your best solution to your problem.

Comment: Kindly thanks for your answer! I don't understand how's Whonix different compared to regular TOR, does it connect to VPN?

Comment: Whonix is a operative system that routes your packets through its gateway out to the internet thus to the first exit node and so on... The only thing you need to do is to connect to the internal network that whonix is creating. More information about the security and other stuff of whonix compare to other TOR distribution can be found [here](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Comparison_with_Others)